# Reading appsettings.json values from C#.NET 6.0 AWS Lambda Function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

It seems to be simple, but it is not working for me...

I am using C#.NET 6.0 for AWS Lambda Function. I am trying to create this Function in Visual Studio 2022. There is no Startup.cs file in this Lambda Function Project. Just a Class Library with Function.

I just want to read the values from appsettings.json file from C# Function. The Json File looks like this...

```
{
  "SQSARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:SQS-Queue1",
  "BucketName": "excel-s3-bucket",
  "ObjectKey": "Sample.xlsx"
}
```

I am reading the values in C# Code as below...

```
config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",true,true)
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .Build();
```

Now I am trying to extract as below...

```
string myValue = config.GetValue<string>("SQSARN");
```

I am getting `Null` value for the above key.

Where am I going wrong here? Any libraries needs to be added here? Please let me know.

Comment: Check the properties of your JSON file, make sure that "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy Always"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I add JSON settings files. I'll assume the file is called `appsettings.json`, and it contains a key `"BucketName"`

1. Add NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`
2. Right-click Project > Add > New Item... > JSON file
3. Add all your settings in your JSON file
4. Json File Properties > Copy to Output Directory = "Copy Always"

Then you can access the settings with code similar to:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");
var config = configuration.Build();
var bucketName = config["BucketName"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your Answer helped me in the right time. Kudos to you :).